# I get 503 error after trying to post request on mydomain/graphql

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

My project is Nuxt.js and i get 503 error on the console for this request
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
503

This problem occure only on the prod environment but on the dev environment it work correctly

I hope someone know the cause of this issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your production env is on a server.

The 503 error HTTP status code is indicating that the server is temporarily unavailable or overloaded and cannot handle the request.
This error is related to server-side issues rather than your Nuxt.js application.

It basically means your server is overloaded due to high volume of traffic or resource-intensive processes.
You can check your servers resource usage and see what your cpu/disk/memory usage is on the moment you get the 503 error.

You can either upgrade your server or optimize your code to be more efficient with your max resources.